# What is the name given to an exporting-only economy?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, markets

In international trading there can be an economy that only exports, but restrict the import to minimum or at all. I cannot recall what the name given to this type of economy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a very specific question, which is unlikely to help any other user in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "autarky" the word you're looking for? That's been used to refer to a self-sufficient economy that does not need imports. As others have written, it's an ideological position that chooses to make a country worse off, and doesn't happen in reality, except for short periods in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: At least autarky has some rational behind it. If you think world trade is too volatile and want to have all essential production at home, or if you are convinced other countries would hurt you through trade autarky would be the way to go. But exporting without importing does not make sense even in these scenarios.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers, Thank you. That's the term I was looking for!. I am studying some closed community (as described in my question), and my argument is that it's getting bigger and wealthier on other's expense. The term that you gave me will help me dive deeper in my study. Thanks again. Sorry I can't thumb you up... :)

Answer (score 0):

The existence of such an economy seems hypothetical. The whole point of exports is to gain foreign currency that one can spend on foreign goods - imports. It is possible that an economy has a trade surplus in several years but it is unrealistic that an economy almost never imports anything.

Comment: How is this related to the question? The OP was not asking for the plausibility of an economy with those conditions. I insist that this should be closed.

Comment: @luchonacho And you have the right to your opinion and to your vote! (Insisting seems a tad strong.)

Comment: As for how this relates to the question: I think this is a negative answer, one that shows an actual answer is unlikely.